# Progress Bar Increment/Decrement

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I need some help with the progress bar from [semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html#/definition). I'm trying to replicate the first example with the increment/decrement button, but for the life of me, can't get it to work, any help on this matter or sample with Javascript code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: theres's no need to put [solved] in the title, your acceptance of an answer shows the question has been answered. :)

Comment: Oups, Thanks Tony ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for that page is [located here](http://semantic-ui.com/javascript/progress.js), and you are looking at this section in particular:

```
$buttons
  .on('click', function() {
    var
      $progress = $(this).closest('.example').find('.ui.progress')
    ;
    if( $(this).hasClass('increment') ) {
      $progress.progress('increment');
    }
    else {
      $progress.progress('decrement');
    }
  })
;
```

As you can see, each button is added a `click` event. Then, `$progress` get assigned to the closest found progress bar. Finally, we check for the class of the button (to know if it is in/decrement) and the `.progress` value gets used accordingly.

While we are at it, here's the HTML they use for the buttons:

```
<div class="example">
  <div class="ui progress">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui icon buttons">
    <div class="decrement ui basic red button"><i class="minus icon"></i></div>
    <div class="increment ui basic green button"><i class="plus icon"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Moustach, your post helped me a lot, with my brain fart ;) I finally got it working !!!! yeah, just added "var semantic=$(this)" so I don't get errors like "ReferenceError: semantic is not defined" and everything check out, again thanks ;)